# Selective output for bidirectional recurrent neural network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Bidirectional Recurrent Neural Network(Bi-RNN) for binary classification.
I searched lots of paper related to that and finally get to know that the output of last time step or all of outputs are used for learning and prediction.

However, I'd like to use the output of certain step, which may not be last step, depending on the input. If **Cth** input is what i want to know, I will use **Cth** output. Because **Cth** output is resutled by all of other hidden states in Bi-RNN, I don't have to use other outputs of time step If I am only interested in **Cth** one.

I know this is little special case but I can't find any example for this case.
(Attention based approach is diffrent from what i want to know. I want to use only one output,which may not be last output, for learning a input sequnece)

Is there any example and research paper related what i mentioned?